# Get Tax Registration ID from logged Company in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

i'm trying to get the Tax Registration ID from current company logged in Acumatica , i found it in the **BAccount** table, but to select it i will need the **BAccountID**. How can i get it ?? [BAccount Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibEa5.png)

Hope someone can help me!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the Branch of the logged in user instead of the company.

The target field will be in BranchBAccount DAC which inherits from BAccount.

Main setting is per Branch and can be overridden in a cascading fashion in Location/BAccount.

[image]

You can use AccessInfo class to get information about logged in user like his Branch.

Example BQL request:

```
BranchBAccount branchBAccount = PXSelectJoin<BranchBAccount, 
                                LeftJoin<Branch, On<Branch.branchCD, Equal<BranchBAccount.branchBranchCD>>>,
                                Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<AccessInfo.branchID>>>.Select(this [or] Base);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I think it will be very useful, another question and hope it does not bother you... how can i get the BranchID ???

Comment: With AccessInfo as in the query from my answer: AccessInfo.branchID. From a graph would be something like Accessinfo.Current.BranchID. And from a graph extension Base.Accessinfo.Current.BranchID.